# remove beginning forward-slash on htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The forward-slash in my htaccess file is having problems. I need this htaccess to work on multiple servers with different domain names.

I am trying to use the %{HTTP_HOST} parameter to make the domain portion of the rewriterule dynamic. It is working for the most part, except that the domain name is getting '/' put in front of domain.com

example:

/domain.com/folder/detail

How can I remove that first '/'? Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/([^\.]+)
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php/$2 [NC,L]
```

I am not trying to redirect to another domain, this htaccess file will be with a project that will need to run on multiple servers(local and remote). They all have different domain names to them. so htaccess needs to be dynamic about it.

On one remote server it is trying to route from the very root of the document not going through the http_host like http://domain.com for example. So this is why I am putting in %{HTTP_HOST}.

The problem is rewriterule is prepending a '/' to the rewrite automatically.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't see how your example matches your code.  I don't see `stain-guide` in your example

Comment: If you want an explicit external redirect, then use the `R` flag.

Comment: I am not trying to redirect, explicitly defining the domain so that one of my remote servers doesnt try to access through from the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/([^\.]+)
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this certainly made progress with the issue. My problem left is that 1. the url insists on adding '.php' to my 'folder' section of the url. 2. the url is not resolving the last argument in the url, its simply ignoring it and loading 'folder.php' without processing trailing argument (this does work on my local)

Comment: Just created a fall back for my code to handle folder.php in the url, so now it still loads the page properly while trying to clean up the url.